# Laravel: form looks like it's disabled

Tags: forms, laravel, disabled-input

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm trying to create a form. However, I can't use in the browser, and it looks like it's disabled. Who can tell me why?

[image]

My css

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

/* FORM */
.form_block {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

My welcome.blade.php part:

```
<section id="s2">
    <div class="container">
        {{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form_block')) }}
            {{ Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com') }}
            {{ Form::submit('Send Email!') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is the error on browser ?
you have try this composer require laravelcollective/html

Comment: laravelcollective/html is installed, and there's no error in my browser. It just looks like the picture and I can't click or type in it

Comment: Some other CSS must be affecting it.  Use your browser devtools to look at the actual rendered HTML, and inspect the applied CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<section id="s2">
    <div class="container">
        {{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form_block', route => 'route.name')) }}
             {{ Form::input('email', 'email_field_name') }}
            {{ Form::submit('Send Email!') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</section>
```

Remember to add a route to handle form submit action!